# "python" in command prompt doesn't work (windows 10)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I downloaded python 1.11 from the python website but whenever I try to launch "python" in command prompt it launches the windows store and tells me to install python.

I ran py -3 and it launches python 3.11 in the command prompt. Is this the only way to access python though why doesn't "python" work?

Comment: No, on windows use `py -3`.

Comment: uninstall python and reinstall it from [python.org](https://www.python.org/) and during installation pick the choice to "Add python to PATH"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add python to Windows `PATH`.
Try using windows search and search for **Edit the system environment variables**, and then click on **Environment variables**. You will see **"User variables"** and **"System variables"**. Find `PATH` variable in both sections. If you cannot find it, Click **"New..."**.

- If you are editing existing `PATH`, add these 2 lines:

```
<Your python installation path>\Python311
<Your python installation path>\Python311\Scripts

E.g.:
C:\Users\<User>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311
C:\Users\<User>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Scripts
```

- If you are creating new `PATH` variable, add the following line:

```
<Your python installation path>\Python311;<Your python installation path>\Python311\Scripts

E.g.:
C:\Users\<User>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311;C:\Users\<User>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Scripts
```

Save the variables and you can access python using `python` on terminals.

***Note***: On some windows, `PATH` is defined as `Path`.